# Function that returns a list of objects that contains another function

Tags: javascript, function, object

Not sure if the title is clear.

The below is my attempt but i got a uncaught

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'.

How do you fix it?

```
function CreateSuspectObjects(name) {
  function speak(){
      return `my name is `+ name;
   }
  return {
    name: name,
    color: name.split(' ')[1],
    speak()
  };
};
```

Comment: The call to `speak()` in the object initializer doesn't make syntactic sense.

Answer (score 3):

`speak()` should be assigned to a key in your object:

```js
function CreateSuspectObjects(name) {
  function speak(){
      return `my name is `+ name;
   }
  return {
    name: name,
        color: name.split(' ')[1],
    speak: speak()
  };
};

console.log(CreateSuspectObjects('x'));
```

or you can return a reference to a function by removing the paranthesis:

```js
function CreateSuspectObjects(name) {
  function speak(){
      return `my name is `+ name;
   }
  return {
    name: name,
        color: name.split(' ')[1],
    speak: speak
  };
};

console.log(CreateSuspectObjects('x'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the third item in the object was a function call, not a key value pair. You want something like `speak: speak()` instead:

```js
function CreateSuspectObjects(name) {
  
  function speak(){
      return "my name is " + name;
   }
 
 return {
    name: name,
    color: name.split(' ')[1],
    speak: speak()
  }
}

let obj = CreateSuspectObjects("Earl");

console.log(obj.speak);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope can it help you.

```js
 function CreateSuspectObjects(name) {
        speak = function() {
           
            return "my name is: "+name;
        }
        return {name: name,
                color: name.split(' ')[1],
                speak: speak()}
    }
    TestResult();
    function TestResult() {
        console.log(CreateSuspectObjects("tran minh huynh"));
    }
```